# JavaCV Insufficient memory, failed to allocate memory

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv, omr

I am developing an OMR(Optical Mark Recognition) application using JavaCV,java interface for OpenCV.The application runs fine for 200 images but after that it fails to allocate memory for IplImage in my code.The allocation error comes when I try to clone imgx and assign it to imgxc1.Can you please suggest a programmatic fix for it? Increasing the heap size seems to be a temporary solution?

Here is the initialization code(where the exception occurs):

```
protected boolean init () throws UnableToLoadImage{
    imgx = new IplImage();
    imgxc1 = new IplImage();
    imgxd1 = new IplImage();
    imgx = cvLoadImage(path+DR+filename);
    if(imgx == null)throw new UnableToLoadImage(path+DR+filename);
    //cvSaveImage("debug/"+filename, imgx);
    imgxc1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgx), imgx.depth(), imgx.nChannels());
    imgxc1 = imgx.clone();//error comes here
    imgxd1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgx), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvCvtColor(imgxc1, imgxd1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    return (imgx != null && imgxc1 != null && imgxd1 != null)?true:false;
}
```

Here is the cleaning up code:

```
public void release() {
    if(imgx != null){

        imgx.release();
        imgxc1.release();
        imgxd1.release();

        cvReleaseImage(imgx);
        cvReleaseImage(imgxc1);
        cvReleaseImage(imgxd1);
    }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 6454368 bytes) in cv::OutOfMemoryError, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52

at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.cvCloneImage(Native Method)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core$AbstractIplImage.clone(opencv_core.java:1005)
at com.omr.app.OmrModel.init(OmrModel.java:200)
at com.omr.app.OmrController$2.doInBackground(OmrController.java:328)
at com.omr.app.OmrController$2.doInBackground(OmrController.java:1)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The error looks like the problem was not heap space limit reached, but rather not enough RAM - Java wanted to allocate more but the OS couldn't give it more.

Comment: when this error came the ram was at 80 percent of the total 4 gb. It does not seem like a ram issue. The application was occupying 340 mb in the task manager when the page counter was 200.

Comment: It's clearly a RAM issue, and as @JiriTousek said, not Java's heap, so increasing the heap size shouldn't even help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks weird. You're assigning `IplImage` objects to your variables, only to overwrite them instantly. You're also leaking at least one presumably native resource in the following case:

```
imgxc1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgx), imgx.depth(), imgx.nChannels());
imgxc1 = imgx.clone();//error comes here
```

The original `imgxc1` object that was created with `cvCreateImage` has no longer references to it, but you didn't release the resources.

If how references work in Java is unclear to you, I'd suggest you do some work on that before continuing with your work. You'll get rid of your redundant double assignment lines and the code will be clearer too.

Edit: Since I've already wasted time on this, let's go through `init()` line by line.

```
protected boolean init () throws UnableToLoadImage{
    imgx = new IplImage();    // Create a new IplImage() even though we won't use it

    imgxc1 = new IplImage();  // Same here. Just food for the garbage collector

    imgxd1 = new IplImage();  // Third completely unnecessary object creation

    imgx = cvLoadImage(path+DR+filename);  // Load an image, the previously created object in imgx is now GC food

    if(imgx == null)throw new UnableToLoadImage(path+DR+filename);
    //cvSaveImage("debug/"+filename, imgx);

    imgxc1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgx), imgx.depth(), imgx.nChannels());  // Create an image with native resources, previous object is GC food

    imgxc1 = imgx.clone();    // Third time assignment to imgxc1, previous object isn't GC food since it holds native resources
    imgxd1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgx), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);  // The first proper use of cvCreateImage
    cvCvtColor(imgxc1, imgxd1, CV_BGR2GRAY);  // Presumably ok
    return (imgx != null && imgxc1 != null && imgxd1 != null)?true:false;  // Doesn't need the ternary operator at all
}
```

The code shows a huge misunderstanding of Java, but if there hadn't been native resources involved, it would only result in some extra object creations which would then be handled by the garbage collector.

Comment: I do release the reference in the release method but you are right about the redundant double assignments.

Comment: @afnan1992 No you don't. You no longer have a reference to the original `imgxc1`, so there's no way you could release it. The garbage collector would free it otherwise, but since it has native resources it can't. If you intend to create a proper application out of this, I strongly suggest getting the basics right.

Comment: The use of native resources is making it a bit confusing. imgxc1 is an instance variable so why don't I have the reference to the original imgxc1? Would be glad if you can educate me here.

Comment: You have one reference (`imgxc1`) and two objects (`cvCreateImage()` and `imgx.clone()`). Since a reference can only refer to a single object, there's no way you can release the first, leaked object (it wouldn't be a problem if the GC could release them, but there's native resources that prevent it). You're missing some very basic things there, because it looks like you're trying to "initialize" a reference before "filling" it.

Comment: so if I say delete the line imgx.clone(), then things should be good? Now I completely understand what you're trying to say. Thanks for dumbing it down for me.Since I am holding on to native resources, there is no way i can release the first object right?

Comment: I doubt you completely understand what I'm saying. What are you trying to do with your code? It looks like more than half of the lines in your init method are unnecessary, and the return clause for some reason uses the ternary operator instead of being just `return imgx != null && imgxc1 != null && imgxd1 != null;`.

Comment: this section of the software was written by another programmer who has left the company, I am trying to clear his mess up.I can explain to you the gist of it, i need to detect hough circles so i remove the background noise and converting the image to have only black and white.

Comment: I meant what is the init method supposed to do. Anyway, if you remove the lines that have `new IplImage();` in them and the `imgxc1 = cvCreateImage()` line, you should be good.

Comment: Why is the new IplImage() line redundant? Is it because it is holding native resources because otherwise the garbage collector will perform the clean up process?

Comment: Now i see why you were frustrated with me, thank you for bearing me. The problem was that I could not differentiate between creating native resources(was treating it as normal java references) and the normal way of creating an object in java.

Comment: Well it's not always obvious if native resources are created or not.